# I want to display the table row as inner table row if the first field is same how to perform this

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<tr ng-model="check" ng-repeat="orderBook in orderBookDetails| orderBy: 'orderBook.no'" value='check=$scope.orderBookDetails.sowNo'>
  <td ng-if='check!=orderBook.no'>{{orderBook.no}}</td>
  <td>{{orderBook.location}}</td>
  <td>{{orderBook.finYr}}</td>
  <td ng-if='orderBook.amount1'>{{orderBook.amount1}}</td>
  <td ng-if='!orderBook.amount1'></td>
  <td ng-if='orderBook.amount2'>{{orderBook.amount2}}</td>
  <td ng-if='!orderBook.amount2'></td>
  <td ng-if='orderBook.amount3'>{{orderBook.amount3}}</td>
  <td ng-if='!orderBook.amount3'></td>
  <td>{{orderBook.amount1--orderBook.amount2--orderBook.amount3}}</td>
  <td ng-if='orderBook.amount4'>{{orderBook.amount4}}</td>

  <td ng-if='!orderBook.amount4'></td>
  <td>
    <button ng-click="getOrderBookDetails(orderBook.sowNo,orderBook.sowStartDate,orderBook.sowEndDate, orderBook.sowValuetoUSD);" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_new_record_modal">Update</button>
```

If `orderBook.no` is same then I have to place that only once and add a `tr` within the `td`

I get a table like this

```
SOW No    Location   Year   Jan     Feb   March    Cum Q4    update
  001      italy     2016   1000                    1000     Update
  001      italy     2017           9000   12000    21000    Update
  002      england   2017   1000    2000            3000     Update
```

But I need a table like

```
SOW No  Location     Year    Jan    Feb    March    Cum Q4   update
    001    italy     + 2016  1000                    1000    Update
    002    england   - 2017  1000    2000            3000     Update
```

Onclick the plus button i need to display the

```
 SOW No   Location   Year   Jan     Feb   March    Cum Q4    update
  001      italy    - 2016  1000                    1000     
                                                             Update
                      2017          9000   12000    21000    
  002      england  - 2017  1000    2000            3000     Update
```

with single update button per row.
 I have implemented like

```
<tr id="hideRow" ng-model="counter" value="counter=1"
                                ng-repeat="orderBook in orderBookDetails| orderBy: 'orderBook.no'"
                                ng-if='orderBook.index==0'>
                                <td>{{orderBook.index}}</td>
                                <td><img alt="Expand row" height="20px;"
                                    ng-src="library/image/expand.jpg"
                                    onclick="showRow('orderBook.no')">{{orderBook.no}}</td>
                                <td>{{orderBook.location}}</td>
                                <td>{{orderBook.finYr}}</td>
                                <td ng-if='orderBook.amount1'>{{orderBook.amount1}}</td>
                                <td ng-if='!orderBook.amount1'></td>
                                <td ng-if='orderBook.amount2'>{{orderBook.amount2}}</td>
                                <td ng-if='!orderBook.amount2'></td>
                                <td ng-if='orderBook.amount3'>{{orderBook.amount3}}</td>
                                <td ng-if='!orderBook.amount3'></td>
                                <td>{{orderBook.amount1--orderBook.amount2--orderBook.amount3}}</td>
                                <td ng-if='orderBook.amount4'>{{orderBook.amount4}}</td>
                                <td ng-if='!orderBook.amount4'></td>
                                <td><button
                                        ng-click="getOrderBookDetails(orderBook.sowNo,orderBook.sowStartDate,orderBook.sowEndDate, orderBook.sowValuetoUSD);"
                                        class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#add_new_record_modal">Update</button>
                            </tr>

                            <tr id="reloadRow"
                                ng-repeat="orderBook in orderBookDetails| orderBy: 'orderBook.no'"
                                ng-if='(orderBook.index!=0 || orderBook.no==$scope.curNo) && orderBook.no!=0'>
                                <td>{{orderBook.index}}+0</td>
                                <td><a ng-click="showRow('orderBook.no')"><img alt="Hide row" height="20px;"
                                    ng-src="library/image/sow2.png"></a>{{orderBook.no}}</td>
                                <td>{{orderBook.location}}</td>
                                <td>{{orderBook.finYr}}</td>
                                <td ng-if='orderBook.amount1'>{{orderBook.amount1}}</td>
                                <td ng-if='!orderBook.amount1'></td>
                                <td ng-if='orderBook.amount2'>{{orderBook.amount2}}</td>
                                <td ng-if='!orderBook.amount2'></td>
                                <td ng-if='orderBook.amount3'>{{orderBook.amount3}}</td>
                                <td ng-if='!orderBook.amount3'></td>
                                <td>{{orderBook.amount1--orderBook.amount2--orderBook.amount3}}</td>
                                <td ng-if='orderBook.amount4'>{{orderBook.amount4}}</td>
                                <td ng-if='!orderBook.amount4'></td>
                                <td><button
                                        ng-click="getOrderBookDetails(orderBook.sowNo,orderBook.sowStartDate,orderBook.sowEndDate, orderBook.sowValuetoUSD);"
                                        class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#add_new_record_modal" disable="disabled">Update</button>
                            </tr>
```

ng-click is not working. i have included a index like for first time a no comes its 0 else 1

Comment: what if you changed your `orderBookDetails` to be an array of `array[orderBook ]` .. so, when you render item, you check it's length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to do with angular function so i did with basic jquery type functions

```
   <tr id="reloadRow"   ng-repeat="orderBook in orderBookDetails| limitTo : 10 | orderBy: 'orderBook.no'"
    ng-if='orderBook.index==0 || orderBook.no==curNo'>
    <td>{{orderBook.index}}</td>
    <td ng-if='orderBook.index==0 && orderBook.no==curNo'><img
    alt="Hide row" height="20px;"
    ng-src="library/image/minimize.jpg" ng-click="hideRow()">&nbsp;{{orderBook.no}}</td>
    <td ng-if='orderBook.index==0 && orderBook.no!=curNo'><img
    alt="Hide row" height="20px;"
    ng-src="library/image/expand.jpg"
    ng-click="showingfull(orderBook.no)">&nbsp;{{orderBook.no}}</td>
    <td ng-if='orderBook.index!=0'></td></tr>
```

The ng-click with two images + and -, index, curNo variables and two functions is used

```
$scope.showingfull = function(sowNo) {
                alert("Inside brand new showing method");
                $scope.curNo = sowNo;
            }


$scope.hideRow = function() {
                    $scope.curNo = 0;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by restructuring the data using a factory so it looked more like this:

```
$scope.orderBookDetails = {
  '001':[
    {
      location:'Italy',
      finYr:'2016',
      amount1:1000,
      amount2:2000
    },
    {
      location:'Italy',
      finYr:'2017',
      amount1:1000
    }
  ],
  '002':[
     ..etc..
  ]
}
```

From there, I used nested tables to display the data for each orderBook number and added an ng-click event to the + and - buttons to toggle the other books with that number.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>SOW No</th>
  <th>Location</th>
  <th>Year</th>
  <th>Jan</th>
  <th>Feb</th>
  <th>March</th>
  <th>Cum Q4</th>
  <th>Update</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="(key,orderBook) in orderBookDetails">
 <td class="no_td">{{ key }}</td>
 <td colspan="7">
  <table ng-repeat="book in orderBook" class="book" ng-if="$index == 0 || orderBook.expanded">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ book.location }}</td>
      <td>
        <button class="expander" ng-click="expandBooks(orderBook)" ng-if="$index == 0">
          <span ng-if="!orderBook.expanded && orderBook.length > 1">+</span>
          <span ng-if="orderBook.expanded || orderBook.length <= 1">-</span>
        </button>
        <span class="spacer" ng-if="$index > 0"></span>

        {{ book.finYr }}
      </td>
      <td>{{ book.amount1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ book.amount2 }}</td>
      <td>{{ book.amount3 }}</td>
      <td>{{ book.amount1 + book.amount2 + book.amount3 }}</td>
      <td><button ng-click="getOrderBookDetails(orderBook)" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_new_record_modal">Update</button></td>        
    </tr>

   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>  
</table>
```

Here is a codepen showing my solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZqObO